# Using a variable for a masked link; discord.py embed posted through webhook; python

Tags: python, embed, discord, discord.py

For a discord bot that will post links, for the URL that it outputs to be masked

```
variable = url + "/collection/" + str(field[1]) + "test"
embed.add_field(name=str(field[0]), value=str("![test]!({variable})"))
```

Do not know how this works

```
embed.add_field(name=str(field[0]), value=str("![test]!( https://www.google.com)"))
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the specific problem you are having with this code.

Comment: value=str("[test]({variable})")) how can I get variable to work within the masked link

Comment: in Javascript it would be (`[test](${variable})`))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
variable = url + "/collection/" + str(field[1]) + "test"
embed.add_field(name=str(field[0]), value="![test]!({})".format(variable))
```

`format` replaces `{}` into the given string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use **f-strings**

```
variable = url + "/collection/" + str(field[1]) + "test"
embed.add_field(name=str(field[0]), value=str(f"![test]!({variable})"))
```

Here is an example of an f-string vs formatting

```
a=1
print('{a}') #prints {a}
print('{}'.format(a)) #prints 1
print(f'{a}') #also prints 1
```